# Selenium searching for ID not allways working?

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

In the past i often run in problems when a website is "lazy loading" -

It helped when i used such a search for the id

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id ("analyst-estimate")
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

now i saw that this is not working for every site

on the following site everything works fine:

```
link = "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AAPL/summary"
options = Options ()
options.add_argument ('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
if platform == "win32": cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
elif platform == "linux": cd = '/chromedriver_linux'
elif platform == "darwin": cd = '/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
driver.get (link)  # Read link
time.sleep (2)  # Wait till the full site is loaded
element = driver.find_element_by_id ("analyst-estimate")
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
time.sleep (1)
```

but on another site (also with an id - it is not working at all)

```
link = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/analysis?p=MSFT"
options = Options ()
options.add_argument ('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
if platform == "win32": cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
elif platform == "linux": cd = '/chromedriver_linux'
elif platform == "darwin": cd = '/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
driver.get (link)  # Read link
time.sleep (2)  # Wait till the full site is loaded
element = driver.find_element_by_id ("YDC-Col1")
# element = driver.find_element_by_id ("Col2-4-QuoteModule-Proxy")
# element = driver.find_element_by_id ("app")
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
time.sleep (1)
```

Why is this not working for the second website?
Its the exact same code - why is he not finding the id - it exists on the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a accept cookies pop up displayed before the page is loaded you have to click that first :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "agree"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "YDC-Col1")))
```

Before testing something in headless check in non headless mode to see the actual behavior , and aif it fails only in headless take a screenshot to know the state of the website during the failure.

you can take screen shot as :

```
try:

    link = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/analysis?p=MSFT"
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(link)  # Read link
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait till the full site is loaded


    element = driver.find_element_by_id("YDC-Col1")
    # element = driver.find_element_by_id ("Col2-4-QuoteModule-Proxy")
    # element = driver.find_element_by_id ("app")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    time.sleep(1)

except:
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("a.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Time.sleep() isn't very stable for waiting for page loads. Switch over to webdriver waits. Also it doesn't seem to take 2 seconds to load.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "YDC-Col1")))
```

Also another issue could be using headless and not setting window size.

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: tried it that way but it is still not working
when using 

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "YDC-Col1")))

i get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: